# Generate x+xx+xxx+xxxx ... for a given integer (for 4 -> 4+44+444...)

Tags: python

I have to incrementally concatenate a given number on each iteration so that it returns a sum and the concatenated string. This is my try:

```
def digit_sum_from_letters(x):
    a = int("%s" % x)
    b = int("%s%s" % (x,x))
    c = int("%s%s%s" % (x,x,x))
    d = int("%s%s%s%s" % (x,x,x,x))
    return a+b+c+d
print digit_sum_from_letters(9)
```

returning `11106`

But I need to generate the sum for whatever given integer so I need a loop but I'm stuck.

Thanks!

Comment: in what way you need a loop? could you be more specific?

Comment: Could you clarify the goal? Are you saying that if a user enters 2, it should be (2 + 22), and if a user enters 3, it should be (3 + 33 + 333)? Or is it something else?

Comment: Note that you only need to compute the sum ONES = 1 + 11 + 111 + ... + 1...11. Once you have that sum, you just need to multiply the given digit by ONES.

Comment: @goodtimeslim yes, for 3 it is 3+33+333

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
>>> def digit_sum(x):
    lst = [str(x)*i for i in range(1,x+1)]
    print '+'.join(lst)
    return sum(map(int, lst))

>>> digit_sum(7)
7+77+777+7777+77777+777777+7777777
8641969
>>> digit_sum(9)
9+99+999+9999+99999+999999+9999999+99999999+999999999
1111111101
>>> digit_sum(3)
3+33+333
369
```

Answer (score 5):

Given `digit` and `n` (for example, `digit=4` and `n=3` is `4 + 44 + 444`), you just need generate a sequence of ones, and multiply its sum by `digit`.

```
digit = 4
n = 3
# 1, 11, 111
ones = [ int("1" * i) for i in range(1, n+1)]
# 4 + 44 + 444 = 4 * (1 + 11 + 111)
answer = digit * sum(ones)
```

Comment: Funny things happen when it's not just a digit :) OP did not make that specification haha

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of ways to do this. I'll start with the solution most similar to yours, and if you want I can introduce a likely faster way :).

```
def digit_sum_from_letters(digit,count):
 suma=0
 cur=digit
 for _ in xrange(count):
  suma+=int(cur)
  cur+=digit
 return suma
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun:

```
def f(n):
    return n*int("123456789"[:n])
```

It gives:

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 24
3 -> 369
4 -> 4936
5 -> 61725
6 -> 740736
7 -> 8641969
8 -> 98765424
9 -> 1111111101
```

Answer (score 2):

Who told you you need a loop? Don't listen to them

```
def fn(n):
  x,z = n,10
  return x*(z*(z**n-1) // (z-1) - n) // (z-1)

print(fn(1)) # 1
print(fn(2)) # 24
print(fn(3)) # 369
print(fn(4)) # 4936
```

EDIT: It's a shame they require you the expression string too. On that part you must use a loop sadly

Answer (score 1):

Following function will do, n is your number(4) m is number of iterations(4, 44, 444, 4444, ...).

```
def digit_sum_from_letters(n, m):
    sum = 0
    # this is the multiplier.
    # throughout the iterations it will be 1, 11, 111, 1111 ...
    currMult = 1
    for i in range(0,m):
        sum += n*currMult
        currMult = currMult*10 + 1
    return sum
```

Example run:

```
>>> sumLetters(9,4 )
11106
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def sum_n(x, n):
    s = 0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        s += int(('%d'*i) % tuple([x]*i))
    return s


In [0]: print(sum_n(9,4))
Out[0]: 11106
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using list compression:

```
x = 9
c = 4
sum([int(str(x) * i) for i in xrange(1,c + 1)])
11106
```